# How to reference `self` in dataclass' fields?

Tags: python, self, python-dataclasses

I am trying to do the equivalent of:

```
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = self.get_b()

    def get_b(self):
        return 1
```

using `@dataclass`. I want to use a `@dataclass` here because there are other (omitted) fields initialized from provided constructor arguments. `b` is one of the fields that is initialized from an instance method's result. Executing this:

```
@dataclass
class A:
    b = self.get_b()

    def get_b(self):
        return 1
```

shows that `self` is not defined in `b`'s scope. Is it possible to get a reference to `self` here?

Comment: call the your_other_class.function instead of using self since it is not in the same context.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the `__post_init__` method.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class A:
    b: int = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self):
        self.b = self.get_b()
```

Not exactly an improvement, is it? The default value assigned to a field is equivalent to a default parameter value in `__init__`, e.g.,

```
def __init__(self, b=0):
    self.b = b
```

Just like you can't use `self` in such a parameter default, you can't use it as the field default value. The default value has to exist *before* the instance actually exists.

We create the field explicitly so that we can pass `init=False`, preventing the generated `__init__` method from expecting an argument to initialize `self.b`.

---

If the function `get_b` is really independent of an instance (that is, you don't need an instance of `A` in order to return the value `1`), you can use an already defined function as a default factory.

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field


@dataclass
class A:
    def get_b(self=None):
        return 1

    b: int = field(default_factory=get_b, init=False)
```

Here, `get_b` will be called as a function with zero arguments (hence the default value for `self` in the definition) rather than be invoked from a class instance. This is, though, rather unorthodox and I wouldn't recommend structuring your code like this.

Comment: for the final part of your answer, wouldn't it be more common to make the function static instead of saying `self=None`?

Comment: It would be, but I didn't want to make that change in case `get_b` was used as an instance method as well later (even though there's no reason for it to be one).

Comment: Also, an instance of `staticmethod` itself is not actually callable; you have to invoke it as an attribute of the class or instance in order for its `__get__` method to return a callable. Here, the actual function `get_b` needs to be passed to `field`. You would have to define `get_b`, use it as the `default_factory` argument, *then* rebind the name to a static method with `get_b = staticmethod(get_b)`.

Comment: Hm, maybe making it a static method, then using `field(default_factory=get_b.__func__, init=False)` isn't *that* bad.

Comment: I'm not thrilled with it, but I would want to see a real example of why `get_b` exists in the first place before deciding how I would want to handle it.

Comment: You're right, it's not pretty either way. And +1 on needing the context to make the better call.