# Initialize dataclass instance with functions

Tags: python, python-3.x, self, python-dataclasses

I'm trying to create a dataclass to store all relevant data in a single object. How can I initialize a dataclass instance where the values are evaluated from functions within the dataclass, which take parameters?

This is where I am so far:

```
@dataclass
class Person: 
    def Name(self):
        return f'My name is {self.name[0]} {self.name[1]}.'

    def Age(self):
        return f'I am {self.age} years old.'

    name: field(default_factory=Name(self), init=True)
    age: field(default_factory=Age(self), init=True)

person = Person(('John', 'Smith'), '100')
print(person)
```

Current output:

```
Person(name=('John', 'Smith'), age='100')
```

This is the output I'm trying to achieve:

```
Person(name='My name is John Smith', age='I am 100 years old')
```

I was trying to use [How to reference `self` in dataclass' fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63065134/how-to-reference-self-in-dataclass-fields) for reference on this topic.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First - and this is rather subtle - I note that it does not work to have `dataclasses.field()` as a type annotation. That is, `name: field(...)` is invalid. I can assume you mean to do `name: str = field(...)`. Here `str` is the type annotation for name.

But even with that approach, you would run into a `TypeError` based on how you are passing the `default_factory` argument - you would need a no-argument callable, though I notice that doesn't seem to help in this use case.

My impression is, it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do with `dataclasses.field(...)` alone, as I believe the docs indicate `default_factory` needs to be a [zero argument callable](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#default-factory-functions).

For instance, `default_factory=list` works as `list()` provides a no-arg constructor.

However, note that the following is not possible:

```
field(default_factory = lambda world: f'hello {world}!')
```

`dataclasses` will not pass a value for `world` to the `default_factory` function, so you will run into an error with such an approach.

The good news is there are a few different alternatives or options to consider in your case, which I proceed to outline below.

### Init-only Variables

To work around this, one option could be to use a combination of [`InitVar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html#init-only-variables) with `field(init=False)`:

```py
from dataclasses import field, dataclass, InitVar


@dataclass
class Person:

    in_name: InitVar[tuple[str, str]]
    in_age: InitVar[str]

    name: str = field(init=False)
    age: str = field(init=False)

    def __post_init__(self, in_name: tuple[str, str], in_age: str):
        self.name = f'My name is {in_name[0]} {in_name[1]}.'
        self.age = f'I am {in_age} years old.'


person = Person(('John', 'Smith'), '100')
print(person)
```

Prints:

```
Person(name='My name is John Smith.', age='I am 100 years old.')
```

### Properties

Another usage could be with *field-properties* in dataclasses. In this case, the values are passed in to the constructor method as indicated (i.e. a `tuple` and `str`), and the `@setter` method for each field-property generates a formatted string, which it stores in a private attribute, for example as `self._name`.

Note that there is undefined behavior when no default values for *field properties* are passed in the constructor, due to how `dataclasses` handles (or rather silently ignores) properties currently.

To work around that, you can use a metaclass such as one I have outlined in [this gist](https://gist.github.com/rnag/d14b05680094b871935a9a30d43d5c0d).

```py
from dataclasses import field, dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:

    name: tuple[str, str]
    age: str

    # added to silence any IDE warnings
    _age: str = field(init=False, repr=False)
    _name: str = field(init=False, repr=False)

    @property
    def name(self):
        return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name: tuple[str, str]):
        self._name = f'My name is {name[0]} {name[1]}.'

    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age

    @age.setter
    def age(self, age: str):
        self._age = f'I am {age} years old.'


person = Person(('John', 'Smith'), '100')
print(person)

person.name = ('Betty', 'Johnson')
person.age = 150
print(person)

# note that a strange error is returned when no default value is passed for
# properties; you can use my gist to work around that.
# person = Person()
```

Prints:

```py
Person(name='My name is John Smith.', age='I am 100 years old.')
Person(name='My name is Betty Johnson.', age='I am 150 years old.')
```

### Descriptors

One last option I would be remiss to not mention, and one I would likely recommend as being a little bit easier to set up than properties, would be the use of [descriptors](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#customized-names) in Python.

From what I understand, descriptors are essentially [an easier approach](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/descriptor.html#pure-python-equivalents) as compared to declaring a ton of properties, especially if the purpose or usage of said properties is going to be quite similar.

Here is an example of a custom descriptor class, named `FormatValue`:

```py
from typing import Callable, Any


class FormatValue:
    __slots__ = ('fmt', 'private_name', )

    def __init__(self, fmt: Callable[[Any], str]):
        self.fmt = fmt

    def __set_name__(self, owner, name):
        self.private_name = '_' + name

    def __get__(self, obj, objtype=None):
        value = getattr(obj, self.private_name)
        return value

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
        setattr(obj, self.private_name, self.fmt(value))
```

It can be used as follows, and works the same as the above example with properties:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass


@dataclass
class Person:
    name: 'tuple[str, str] | str' = FormatValue(lambda name: f'My name is {name[0]} {name[1]}.')
    age: 'str | int' = FormatValue(lambda age: f'I am {age} years old.')


person = Person(('John', 'Smith'), '100')
print(person)

person.name = ('Betty', 'Johnson')
person.age = 150
print(person)
```

Prints:

```py
Person(name='My name is John Smith.', age='I am 100 years old.')
Person(name='My name is Betty Johnson.', age='I am 150 years old.')
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thanks for the super detailed answer!

Comment: no problem! glad it was helpful. I also copied over my comments to the answer, but hopefully this is well rounded-out and provides various solutions to the issue at hand.